# Why I can not make object of abstract class here and I got error of Non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I am getting an error while executing this code. Why I am getting Non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context?

```
  class javatest{
     public abstract class Employee {
            public abstract void names();

                 }

      public class Banani extends Employee{
            @Override
            public void names(){
               System.out.println("I am at Banani.");
             }
          }

       public class Shyamoli extends Employee{
              @Override
              public void names(){
              System.out.println("I am at Shyamoli");
       }
   }

        public static void main(String[] args){


           Employee south = new Banani();
           Employee north = new Shyamoli();
           north.names();
           south.names();
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either move your classes outside or make them static.

```
public abstract class Employee {
    public abstract void names();
    }

public class Banani extends Employee {
    @Override
    public void names() {
        System.out.println("I am at Banani.");
    }
}

public class Shyamoli extends Employee {
    @Override
    public void names() {
        System.out.println("I am at Shyamoli");
    }
}

class javatest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee south = new Banani();
        Employee north = new Shyamoli();
        north.names();
        south.names();
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not implement the offices() method...

Answer (score 0):

In your code example None of the subclasses implements abstract method **offices()** , because of this **Banani** and **Shyamoli** are both abstract and can't be instntiated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an IDE, which will give you enough information.

Answer (score 0):

corrected code below

```
abstract class Employee {
public abstract void names();

public abstract void offices();
}

class Banani extends Employee {
@Override
public void names() {
    System.out.println("I am at Banani.");
}

@Override
public void offices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}

class Shyamoli extends Employee {
@Override
public void names() {
    System.out.println("I am at Shyamoli");
}

@Override
public void offices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}

public class javatest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee south = new Banani();
    Employee north = new Shyamoli();
    north.names();
    south.names();
}
}
```